How to enable debug logs in node-postgres?
I'm working on a Node.js application that uses node-postgres (pg) to interact with a PostgreSQL database. During development and debugging, I need more detailed logs to understand what's happening with the database queries etc.
I've heard that node-postgres uses the debug module internally for logging, but I'm not sure how to enable debug logs specifically for node-postgres.
Could someone please provide a step-by-step guide on how to enable debug logs for node-postgres either through environment variables or programmatically within a Node.js application?
Thank you in advance for your help!

"I've heard that node-postgres uses the debug module internally for logging" - no it doesn't. Where have you heard that?
